# Ruby HTTP POST - Errors

Tags: ruby, http, post

Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error when doing this POST? I pulled the snippet from [the Ruby-docs page](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

```
undefined method `hostname' for #URI::HTTP:0x10bd441d8 URL:http://ws.mittthetwitapp.com/ws.phpmywebservice (NoMethodError)
```

Perhaps I am missing a require or something?

```
require 'net/http'

uri= URI('http://ws.mywebservice.com/ws.php')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req.set_form_data('xmlPayload' => '<TestRequest><Message>Hi Test</Message></TestRequest>')

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
http.request(req)
end

case res
 when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
 # OK
else
 res.value
end
```

Comment: use ``URI.parse("http://ws.mywebservice.com/ws.php")``

Comment: Thanks. Same error when doing so:

Comment: Error: res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|

Comment: It should be `uri.host`.

Comment: changing to uri.host fixed it thanks. please post as the answer so I can give you credit

Comment: `uri.host` is correct, as is `uri.hostname`. And, the example code works correctly on Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a version of Ruby prior to 1.9.3, you should use `uri.host`.

`URI#hostname` was added in Ruby 1.9.3. It **is different** than `URI#host` in that it removes brackets from IPv6 hostnames. For non-IPv6 hostnames it should behave identically.

The implementation (from [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/URI/Generic/hostname)):

```
def hostname
  v = self.host
  /\A\[(.*)\]\z/ =~ v ? $1 : v
end
```