# undefined method `hostname' for "'http://www.google.com/":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code to get `google.com`

```
class Geocoder
    def self.locate()

        uri="http://www.google.com/"



        puts Net::HTTP.get(uri)

end
```

but i faced with the erorr:

```
undefined method `hostname' for "'http://www.google.com/":String (NoMethodError)
```

I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434507/ruby-http-post-errors), and my ruby version is: `ruby 2.2.1`

Comment: You also have a single quote inside your double-quoted string, there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're missing parsing the string into a URI... Here is what it should look like:

```
class Geocoder
  def self.locate(address)
    escaped_address = URI.escape(address) 
    uri = URI.parse(escaped_address)
    puts Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  end
end
```